# Java Jadler : Jetty conflict

Tags: java, http, testing, mocking, jetty

I want to mock http request in my Junit test. So I use [Jadler Project](https://github.com/jadler-mocking/jadler/wiki). When I run my test and send my http request, I have this exception :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.AsyncContext"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:806)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:487)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:625)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.<init>(AbstractHttpConnection.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.<init>(AsyncHttpConnection.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.newConnection(SelectChannelConnector.java:285)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager.newConnection(SelectChannelConnector.java:325)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.newEndPoint(SelectChannelConnector.java:272)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager.newEndPoint(SelectChannelConnector.java:331)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.createEndPoint(SelectorManager.java:842)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:496)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$1.run(SelectorManager.java:290)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

At the beginning my dependencies looks like that for JAdler :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.jadler</groupId>
    <artifactId>jadler-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.jadler</groupId>
    <artifactId>jadler-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.jadler</groupId>
    <artifactId>jadler-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

After serveral search, I understand why I have this exception. To solve it, I had to change my dependencies like that :

```
    <dependency>
  <groupId>net.jadler</groupId>
  <artifactId>jadler-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.jadler</groupId>
  <artifactId>jadler-jetty</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>8.1.18.v20150929</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.jadler</groupId>
  <artifactId>jadler-junit</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I understand that jetty doesn't use javax.servlet.AsyncContext of org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet but it uses javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api v3.0.1.

Someone know why ? Better solution ?

My JDK version is 1.6.45.

If you need more information like my test sources tell me.

**EDIT 1** : mvn dependency:tree

```
+- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.6:compile
+- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
+- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.5:compile
|  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
+- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.0:compile
+- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
+- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
+- ant:ant-jakarta-oro:jar:1.6:compile
+- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
+- struts:struts:jar:1.2.9:compile
|      +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.1.4:compile
|      +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.7:compile
|  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.5.1:compile
+- oracle:orai18n:jar:14:compile
+- oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.1.0.7.0:provided
+- oracle:xdb:jar:11.1.1.2.0:compile
+- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
+- javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.12:test (scope not updated to compile)
+- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.0:compile
|      +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.0:compile
+- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.0:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
|      +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
|      +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
|      +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
+- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
|  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
+- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:test
+- net.jadler:jadler-core:jar:1.1.2:test
|      +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
|  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:test
+- net.jadler:jadler-jetty:jar:1.1.2:test
+- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:8.1.18.v20150929:test
|      +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:8.1.18.v20150929:test
|  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:8.1.18.v20150929:test
|     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:8.1.18.v20150929:test
|        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:8.1.18.v20150929:test
+- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:test
   \- net.jadler:jadler-junit:jar:1.1.2:test
```

Comment: First, and most important: [Java 1.6 was EOL (End of Life) back in 2013](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) and [Jetty 8 was EOL in 2014](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html).  Second, can you do a `mvn dependency:tree` for your project and included it in your question?

Comment: Yes but I don't have the choice for Java 1.6 and JAdler uses Jetty 8 max. I add my dependencies tree in my question.

Comment: Don't see the `dependency:tree` in the question.

Comment: Sorry I would say I will add my dependency tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with an update of my JDK (6 -> 7) and my tomcat (6 -> 7 for servlet-api 3.x) the bug is fixed. Thanks to [Joakim Erdelft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775715/joakim-erdfelt). I think it's servlet-api 3.x who fixed up my problem.

My new dependency:tree :

```
+- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.6:compile
+- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
+- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.5:compile
|  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
+- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.0:compile
+- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
+- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
+- ant:ant-jakarta-oro:jar:1.6:compile
+- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
+- struts:struts:jar:1.2.9:provided
|      +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.1.4:provided
|      +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.7:provided
|  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.5.1:provided
+- oracle:orai18n:jar:14:compile
+- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.4:provided
+- oracle:xdb:jar:11.2.0.3.0:compile
+- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
+- javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
|  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.12:test (scope not updated to compile)
+- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.0:compile
|      +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.0:compile
+- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.0:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
|      +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
|      +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
|      +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:compile
+- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
|  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
+- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.14.RELEASE:test
+- net.jadler:jadler-core:jar:1.1.2:test
|      +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
|  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:test
+- net.jadler:jadler-jetty:jar:1.1.2:test
|      +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:8.1.11.v20130520:test
|      |      +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:8.1.11.v20130520:test
|      |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:8.1.11.v20130520:test
|      |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:8.1.11.v20130520:test
|      |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:8.1.11.v20130520:test
|  \- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:test
   \- net.jadler:jadler-junit:jar:1.1.2:test
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the servlet-api in your dependency tree twice.

```
+- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
+- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:test
```

Drop the `javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4`

And then mark `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1` as `<scope>provided</scope>`

Comment: Yes I know, but it's not the problem. My project need servlet-api 2.4 so I put them at provided. But to use jetty 8, I had to add servlet-api 3 in scope test instead of org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax-servlet cause the used AsyncContext class is in this library. I put my first dependency of jadler in my question before putting servlet-api 3. AsyncContext : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html

Comment: The servlet jars are sealed and contain signed/protected classes, you can't have both on the classpath at the same time.  That will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since Jadler 1.2.0 you can use a servlet-free implementation of the Jadler stub server. More on the topic: https://github.com/jadler-mocking/jadler/wiki/Using-the-Alternative-Stub-Server-Implementation